# Finding minimum value in an array of dicts

Tags: python, arrays, min, array-of-dict

I have an array like the following:

```
people = [{'node': 'john', 'dist': 3}, 
          {'node': 'mary', 'dist': 5}, 
          {'node': 'alex', 'dist': 4}]
```

I want to compute the minimum of all the 'dist' keys. For instance, in the above example, the answer would be 3.

I wrote the following code:

```
min = 99999
for e in people:
    if e[dist] < min:
        min = e[dist]
print "minimum is " + str(min)
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`min`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) function:

```
minimum = min(e['dist'] for e in people)
# Don't call the variable min, that would overshadow the built-in min function
print ('minimum is ' + str(minimum))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
min(x['dist'] for x in people)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a generator expression to create a list with all keys and then use the built-in min function:

```
min(x['dist'] for x in people)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
min(people, key=lambda x:x['dist'])['dist']
```